# Extending swagger rules

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am new to openapi swagger. While exploring the yaml and the rules,  I wish to enforce my own rules that swagger editor must follow. Like all get requests must start with MLGetDataModule_ . Some help in this regards will be highly appreciated. 
I did read the extending the open api specification from [Link](https://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-9-extending-the-openapi-specification/) but it talks about adding new properties and not adding new rules . Please guide .